# CSS add specificity to :host pseudo class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, custom-element, css-specificity

I'm trying to add specificity to the `:host` pseudo class so that it doesn't get overridden by the universal (`*`) selector outside the custom element.

I see that adding a selector in the `:host` function like: `:host(.some-class)`, doesn't give it class level specificity.

I also tried using the custom-element tag name as a selector `my-element`, but no luck.

Can anyone suggest a way to give `:host` higher specificity or the `*` lower specificity?

Comment: Might you be looking for `host-context()` instead?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:host-context()

Comment: `:host-context(my-element)` is still weaker than `*`

Comment: To overwrite `*` you can use something like `.my-class * `. You can then use `.my-class p` to overwrite the styles for p tags only. You should generally not use `*` unless really necesarry.

Comment: you can't. you'll have to explicitely redefine the CSS properties with !important suffix